# How to get a value from a child class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a simple 5 star voting system and I'm trying to get the numeric value of my href element. The HTML works great but I'm not sure how to get the numeric value for the click event.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="voting"> 
    <span class="rating_container"> 
        <span class="star_container">  
            <a href="#" class="star star_1" >1<span class="rating">Terrible</span></a>   
            <a href="#" class="star star_2" >2<span class="rating">Bad</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="star star_3" >3<span class="rating">OK</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="star star_4" >4<span class="rating">Good</span></a>   
            <a href="#" class="star star_5" >5<span class="rating">Great</span></a>   
        </span> 
    </span> 
</div>
```

My jQuery click event looks like this:

```
$('.star').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

   // How can I get the numeric value of the clicked star (e.g., 5,6,7 etc)

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
var n = this.firstChild.data;
```

Or this:

```
var n = this.className.split("_")[1];
```

---

If you need to convert from a string to a number, add this:

```
n = parseInt(n, 10);
```

Comment: Very nice, very nice. I thought using lots of jQuery... :)

Comment: Initially I'd ask for an explanation, then I realized the firstChild is the textNode before the span.

Comment: works great.  I'm assuming data grabs just that and ignores the span element correct?

Comment: @gdoron: Thanks, I like my *'not enough jQuery'* answers. ;-)

Comment: @Paul: Yes, the `.firstChild` is the text node, and `.data` gets the text value of the node. A person could also use `.nodeValue` instead of `.data`. Does the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `data-tag`.

```
<div id="voting"> 
    <span class="rating_container"> 
        <span class="star_container">  
            <a href="#" data-val="1" class="star star_1" >1<span class="rating">Terrible</span></a>   
            <a href="#" data-val="2" class="star star_2" >2<span class="rating">Bad</span></a>
            <a href="#" data-val="3" class="star star_3" >3<span class="rating">OK</span></a>
            <a href="#" data-val="4" class="star star_4" >4<span class="rating">Good</span></a>   
            <a href="#" data-val="5" class="star star_5" >5<span class="rating">Great</span></a>   
        </span> 
    </span> 
</div>
```

and then in my click handler,

```
$('.star').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   $(this).data('val'); //should return you the number
});
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use `[data-*]` attributes, because it's the right solution.

Comment: `text` will give you the span text as well. won't it?

Comment: I'll +1 as well because this is a much more future-proof way, in case the HTML structure ever needs to be updated.

Comment: @gdoron You are right http://jsfiddle.net/C4F6L/. Thanks. Could use `.contents()` and get the text node but that would be too much of coding